# Retorno de dados php para angularJS

Tags: php, html5, angularjs

Boa noite pessoal.

Estou fazendo um CRUD com angular e php.
Já consegui cadastrar dados no banco, mas não estou conseguindo pegar esses dados e exibir no html. Acho que é o arquivo, buscar.php, que não está certo.

Segue o link do meu git onde está o código.
https://github.com/GugaSevero/CRUD_AngularJS

Segue meu php de busca.

```
<?php
$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'angularDB';
$host = 'localhost';

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $password, $db);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$usuario = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($usuario);
```

Meu angular:

```
$scope.carregarUsuarios = function () {
        $http.get("php/buscar.php").then(function (retorno){
            console.log(retorno.data);
            //$scope.usuarios = data;
        });
    };
```

Comment: Pg_fetch_assoc nao seria do PostgreSQL e nao doMySQL no seu arquivo vuscar.php?

Comment: Não sei @GiancarloGiulin, peguei esse esse código de um outro post desse forum americano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui.

O problema é que eu estava com meu código angular da seguinte forma:

```
$scope.carregarUsuarios = function () {

}
```

Quando o certo é

```
var carregarUsuarios = function () {

}
```

E como eu descrevi acima, o meu php tinha que ficar assim:

```
$usuario = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users");

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$return = array();

while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($usuario)) {
    array_push($return, $dados);
}

echo json_encode($return);
```

Pronto!

Agradeço, mesmo assim pelo retorno de vocês.

Comment: Marque a sua resposta como correta.

Answer (score 0):

na função abaixo, você não tem a variavel usuario, ela vai estar undefined, quando você utiliza o serviço Get, você só pode passar um parâmetro "url", no caso você está passando 2 parâmetros Url e mais um.

```
$scope.carregarUsuarios = function () {
 $http.get("php/buscar.php", usuario)
}
```

o método ficaria da seguinte forma.

```
    $scope.carregarUsuarios = function () {
      $http.get("php/buscar.php").then(function(retorno){
          $scope.usuarios = retorno.data;
          });
     }
```

Comment: tirei o usuario da function, mas mesmo assim não retorna os dados.


$scope.carregarUsuarios = function () {
   $http.get("php/buscar.php").success(function (data){
    $scope.usuarios = data;
   });
  };

Comment: Primeiro troca para o Then ao invez do sucesso, e verifica o que está retornando dentro do retorno.data @GustavoSevero, e verifica também o retorno.status

Comment: eu fiz o que você sugeriu:

$scope.carregarUsuarios = function () {
   $http.get("php/buscar.php").then(function (retorno){
    console.log(retorno.data);
    //$scope.usuarios = data;
   });
  };

E nada aparece no console.

OBS: Como coloca código identado, formatado, aqui?

Comment: aqui no comentário nao tem como .. pega pfv o retorno.status -> se for 200 está tudo OK na web e problema reamente é no lado server

Comment: eu acho que o problema está no php.
Vou fazer esse teste e te aviso.

Comment: Não aparece nada no console...
Fiz um console.log(retorno.status) e nada.

Comment: consegui, corrigi meu php... Os dados aparecem no console, mas não estou conseguindo fazer eles aparecer na tela.

mudei, corrigi meu php... Os dados são retornados, consigo ver eles no console, mas não consigo exibir no html.

$scope.carregarUsuarios = function () {
   $http.get("php/buscar.php").then(function (data){
    console.log(data);
    $scope.usuarios = data;
   });
  };

Comment: Já tentou exibir o objeto ? `{{usuarios}}`. Você pode criar um alias pro controller: `ng-controller="myCrudCtrl as Ctrl"`, e depois chamar:  `Ctrl.usuarios`

Comment: E pelo que estou vendo, vc está usando o `json_encode()` antes de criar a lista e tratar os dados da saída. Essa saída não tem nenhuma coleção.

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma função para criar o arquivo json

```
function createJson($fileName, $data){
    // "a" representa que o arquivo é aberto para ser escrito
    $fp = fopen($fileName.".json", "a");
    // Escreve "exemplo de escrita" no bloco1.txt
    $escreve = fwrite($fp, json_encode($data));
    // Fecha o arquivo
    fclose($fp);
}
```

No controller altere sua função existente para o seguinte codigo

```
var Controllers = angular.module('AppController', []);

Controllers.controller('ListCtrl',['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http){    
    $http.get('http://localhost/json/arquivo_criado.json').success(function(data){  
        $scope.retorno = data;
        console.log(data);
    });  
}]);
```

Comment: mudei, corrigi meu php... Os dados são retornados, consigo ver eles no console, mas não consigo exibir no html.

$scope.carregarUsuarios = function () {
   $http.get("php/buscar.php").then(function (data){
    console.log(data);
    $scope.usuarios = data;
   });
  };

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade o seu problema deve estar acontecendo pois você NÃO está retornando o resultado da pesquisa como uma array, e sim como um resultado sql simples, ou seja, o angular vai conseguir ler, porém não seria possível transcrever para um ng-repeat (ou outro tratamento), já que você está criando um objeto json 'inválido'.

O que você deve fazer é criar um php que consiga transcrever o seu resultado no seguinte formato:

```
[
    {id:1,cliente:'nome do cliente 1',estado_civil:'solteiro'..},
    {id:2,cliente:'nome do cliente 2',estado_civil:'casado'..},
    {id:3,cliente:'nome do cliente 3',estado_civil:'viuvo'..},
    [.. etc ..]
]
```

Para isso você pode usar um código semelhante a esse:

```
function usuarios(){
    $data = array();
    $qry = sql("select * from users");
    $i=0;
    foreach($qry as $r) {
        foreach ($r as $j=>$k) {
            if(!is_int($j)){
                $data[$i][$j] = $k;
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

Recomendo cautela no momento de fazer esse get, especialmente no que diz respeito ao criar um arquivo json. A partir do momento que você escreve um novo json e o grava no servidor, ele estará disponível para qualquer pessoa que consiga acessar sua estrutura de pastas.

Com a necessidade de um sql para obter os dados, sua aplicação fica mais segura.

Já na parte do seu AngularJs, na verdade é preferível que você utilize uma função com `var` ao invés de `$scope` para obter esses dados. Pois criando um novo $scope, você aumenta a possibilidade de erros, já que ela cria interação com DOM e aumenta a necessidade de verificações do AngularJs.

O único detalhe disso é que o seu resultado do php vai ser assim:

```
data: [
    {id:1,cliente:'nome do cliente 1',estado_civil:'solteiro'..},
    {id:2,cliente:'nome do cliente 2',estado_civil:'casado'..},
    {id:3,cliente:'nome do cliente 3',estado_civil:'viuvo'..},
    [.. etc ..]
]
```

Então o seu código no AngularJs, deve fazer retorno à array `DATA`, ficando assim:

```
var carregarUsuarios = function () {
    $http.get("php/buscar.php").then(function (retorno){
        $scope.usuarios = retorno.data;
    });
};
```

Repare na definição do `$scope.usuarios`, eu digo que eu quero atribuir o 'retorno' e depois chamo a 'array', ou seja, `retorno.data`.

Complementando ainda mais, se você deseja utilizar multiplas funções no php, basta fazer o seguinte:

```
//utilize a url da seguinte maneira
$http.get("php/buscar.php?action=carregarUsuarios")
//ou chamando outra função
$http.get("php/buscar.php?action=maisFuncao")
```

E o Php:

```
switch($_GET['action']) {
    case 'carregarUsuarios': carregarUsuarios();
    break;

    case 'maisFuncao': maisFuncao();
    break;
}

function carregarUsuarios() {
    //sua função aqui
}
function maisFuncao() {
    //sua função aqui
}
```